# Angular + Nativescript Code Sharing Project Debugging

Tags: android, angular, debugging, nativescript, nativescript-codesharing

I am looking for a way to run the application in debug mode. The nativescript client docs say to use `tns debug android` as well as `tns debug android` --emulator' for emulator however I cannot get this to work. The applciation is a Nativescript + Angular code sharing project with sass. The following command would make a brand new code sharing project:

```
ng new -c=@nativescript/schematics sass-project --shared --style=scss
```

If needing to read more on code sharing project creations you can go [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/creating-a-new-project.)

I tried a regular nativescript application and the command seems to work so I am not sure if there is a slightly different way you need to do in order to debug a code sharing project.

Below is the following error Log I get on a physical and emulated device:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add "- - bundle" to the command you use.

Comment: I can try it. I think that is only for running regular such as 'tns run android --bundle'